# Innosetup - problem putting icon on uninstaller in start menu

Tags: windows-10, icons, inno-setup

I'm using Innosetup for a very simple Windows C++ app. It just has an icon for the main EXE in the start menu group, plus another icon for the uninstaller (`unins000.exe`, created by Innosetup).

In the `[Files]` section of the script is:

```
Source: "C:\...\telecine.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\...\Telecine.ico"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\...\uninstall.ico"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
```

and in the `[Icons]` section:

```
Name: "{autoprograms}\Nightshade Arts\Telecine\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; IconFilename: "{app}\Telecine.ico"
Name: "{autoprograms}\Nightshade Arts\Telecine\Uninstall"; Filename: "{app}\unins000.exe"; IconFilename: "{app}\uninstall.ico"
```

What works: the two entries are in the program group, the shortcut to `Telecine.exe` has the `Telecine.ico` icon next to it, the shortcut to the uninstaller works.

Problem: the uninstaller icon is not the one in `uninstall.ico`, it is something else, probably contained in `unins000.exe` itself.

Not sure what has gone wrong. `uninstall.ico` is there is the app directory, and it contains the right icon. Just doesn't show up.

Not sure where I've gone wrong?

Comment: Windows guidelines specify that the start menu should not contain an entry for uninstalling, and in fact [Windows will try remove such a shortcut if it finds one](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20190319-00/?p=102342), so really you should not worry about doing this.

Comment: I know! I still want one there though (it's my software, not Microsoft's ....). In the end it suddenly worked for no good reason that I could see, anyway.